# Get table names if month is greater than 8th of current year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to fetch the the tables for archiving using SSIS for that i am writing query so in query i am looping trough year by year to get that years created tables list here is what i wanted to do,

```
1) Get the tables created in year which is equal to looping year variable ?
2) If the current year month is greater than 8 then select then select the tables for the last year otherwise select till year before
```

I tried as ,

```
 SELECT name,month(create_date),YEAR(create_date)  
 FROM sys.Tables where  (name like 'F%' OR name like 'G%') 
  and 
   ((month(getdate())>8 and datediff(YEAR,create_date,GETDATE()) = loopVariableDifferance)
      or (datediff(YEAR,create_date,GETDATE())= loopVariableDifferance-1) )
 order by name

 //loopVariableDifferance is start with 5 for 2008 ,4 for 2009,3 for 2010 continues till 0 for 2013
```

all i want is get tables for 2008 in first loop, 2009 in second, 2010 in third loop, 2011 in fourth loop and 2012 if the current month of current year is greater than 8

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you the table names.

```
    DECLARE @tables TABLE(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), name VARCHAR(500),YearsAgo INT, YearCreated INT, MonthCreated INT);
    DECLARE @loopmax INT, @Thisyertest INT, @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @Thisyertest = 1;

    IF MONTH(GETDATE()) > 8
        SET @Thisyertest = 0; /*If this is 0 it will include 2012 results*/

    INSERT INTO @tables(name,YearsAgo, YearCreated, MonthCreated)
    SELECT 
    name
    , DATEDIFF(YEAR,create_date,GETDATE()) YearsAgo
    , YEAR(create_date) YearCreated
    , MONTH(create_date) MonthCreated
    FROM sys.Tables 
    ORDER BY YearCreated ASC, MonthCreated ASC, name

    SET @loopmax = 5 /*Years ago*/
    WHILE @loopmax > (0 + @Thisyertest) /*We offset 1 less loop if we need to exclude last year*/
    BEGIN
        PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@loopmax);

        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @tables T1 WHERE T1.YearsAgo = @loopmax)
        BEGIN
            SELECT ABS(5-@loopmax+1) LoopNumber, id,name,YearsAgo, YearCreated, MonthCreated
            FROM @tables T1
            WHERE T1.YearsAgo = @loopmax;
        END
        SET @loopmax = @loopmax - 1;
    END
```